# Many to many relationship with the same entity in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

When I implement many-to-many relationship between two classes, and configure its composite primary key using fluent api, then instead of creating 2 columns in the database, EF Core creates three columns.

**UserReport.cs**

```
public class UserReports
{
    public int ReporterId { get; set; }
    public User Reporter { get; set; }

    public int ReporteeId { get; set; }
    public User Reportee { get; set; }
}
```

**User.cs**

```
public class User: IdentityUser<int>
{
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string KnownAs { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastActive { get; set; }

    public ICollection<UserReports> Reporters { get; set; } = new Collection<UserReports>();
    public ICollection<UserReports> Reportees { get; set; } = new Collection<UserReports>();
}
```

**ApplicatiobDbContext.cs**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserReports>()
   .HasKey(ru => new { ru.ReporterId, ru.ReporteeId});

modelBuilder.Entity<UserReports>()
   .HasOne(ru => ru.Reportee)
   .WithMany(u => u.Reporters)
   .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

modelBuilder.Entity<UserReports>()
   .HasOne(ru => ru.Reporter)
   .WithMany(u => u.Reportees)
   .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

**Migration**

After the adding the migrations the EF core generating this type of migration, which is creating an extra columns

```
ReporterId1 = table.Column<int>(nullable: true)

migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "ReportUsers",
        columns: table => new
        {
           ReporterId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
           ReporteeId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
           ReporterId1 = table.Column<int>(nullable: true),
           Message = table.Column<string>(nullable: false)
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the mention of `HasForeignKey` in your configuration that's why the confusion for mapping the foreign key has been arisen as it is `many-to-many` with same the entity. Update your configuration as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserReports>()
   .HasKey(ru => new { ru.ReporterId, ru.ReporteeId});

modelBuilder.Entity<UserReports>()
   .HasOne(ru => ru.Reportee)
   .WithMany(u => u.Reporters)
   .HasForeignKey(ru => ru.ReporteeId); // <-- Here it is
   .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

modelBuilder.Entity<UserReports>()
   .HasOne(ru => ru.Reporter)
   .WithMany(u => u.Reportees)
   .HasForeignKey(ru => ru.ReporterId); // <-- Here it is
   .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

Comment: @MalikHaseeb Great to hear that your problem has been solved.